# Can't deploy function with firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am facing problem with deploying cloud function in firebase CLI. I have cloned the "functions-samples" repo from github and then ran the deploy command in "quickstarts/big-ben" project of this repo. 
I ran these following command as instructed:

```
cd functions
npm install
cd ..
firebase deploy
```

After that my I got this output in my power shell

```
=== Deploying to 'fire-campus'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
!  functions: missing necessary APIs. Enabling now...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...

Error: Timed out waiting for APIs to enable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

I have enabled these APIs in google cloud platform- Firebase Remote Congig API, Firebase Rules API, Google Cloud RuntimeConfig API.

What else I need to enable to activate the required APIs in firebase CLI?
Do I need to signup for google cloud function. I dont have payment option that requires in the signup form.

Comment: I just encountered this issue a minute ago and after trying again, it resolved on it's own. It might be related to some issues Google's Cloud Platform has been having tonight.

Comment: So I don't need to sign up for cloud function in google cloud platform, right? @ABabin

Comment: Nope. I saw the repeated `functions: waiting for APIs to activate...` lines after trying to deploy an app for the first time, and after trying again 5 minutes later, it went through.

Comment: OK. Thanks :) I am trying here from last night. :p

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a while to activate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved automatically after two days. May be this was a temporary problem. There is no need to sign up for the google cloud function in google cloud platform. I guess that service has no relation with firebase cloud function.

Comment: Actually, Firebase Cloud Functions are kind of an abstraction over Google Cloud Functions that allow easier setup for firebase DB/Auth/etc triggers and streamlined authentication and use of firebase resources in a function.

You can use Google Cloud Functions console to monitor your functions, customise things like memory, timeouts, etc + also test your functions.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I just used a proxy in my terminal as the following:

```
export http_proxy=YOUR_PROXY
export https_proxy=YOUR_PROXY
```

After than the problem solved. Note that your proxy should be http(s) and socks not working.